# What are the types of the elements of my 2D array? (new to C)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, types, initialization

So I have the code below and I am wondering what the types of my elements are. I want them to be integers but I am not sure why when I assign a zero to a certain set of indices I have to use apostrophes. What would the type of my elements be?
Output is a 10by10 array of zeros but I need the elements to be integers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int accumulator[10][10];
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            accumulator[i][j] = '0';
            printf("%c ", accumulator[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'0'` is the value of the character `0`, which has the value `48` in decimal, while `0` is the integer `0`.  To print numbers rather than characters, use `%d` and get rid of the single quotes.  It makes no sense for you to be using characters for this.

Comment: `'0'` will have the integer value 48 - the character code for the character `0` (unless you are using EBCDIC or something).

Comment: The lvalue `accumulator[i][j]` has type `int` as you would expect.

Comment: Your confusion arose because you wrote `printf("%c ", accumulator[i][j])`.  I'm not sure why you did that.  If you're thinking of your array as containing integers (as the declaration `int accumulator[10][10]` suggests), you want `printf("%d ", accumulator[i][j])`, to print integers.

Answer (score 1):

For arithmetic, use the int 0.  For character strings, use the char '0'.

```
printf("Number %d\n", 0);
printf("Char %c\n", '0');
```

Output:

```
Number 0
Char 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
accumulator[i][j] = '0';
```

the integer character constant `'0'` has the type int and the value of the code of the character '0' For example in ASCII it is equal tp 48.

If you want to initialize the array with zeroes then you could either initialize the array in its declaration like

```
int accumulator[10][10] = { 0 };
```

or write

```
accumulator[i][j] = 0;
```

As for your question then the type of elements of the two-dimensional array is `int[10]`. That is elements of the array are one-dimensional arrays that in turn have the type of their elements `int`.

You can rewrite the declaration like

```
int ( accumulator[10] )[10];
```

Or you could introduce a typedef name like for example

```
typedef int T[10];
```

and then rewrite the declaration of the two-dimensional array like

```
T accumulator[10];
```

Now it is visually seen that the type of elements of the array is `T` that corresponds to the type `int[10]`.

In this expression

```
accumulator[i][j]
```

the sibexpression

```
accumulator[i]
```

gives the i-th element of the array that as it was pointed out is a one-demensional array. Applying to the above expression the subscript operator you get an element of the element of the two-dimensional array

```
( accumulator[i] )[j]
```

that has the type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> why when I assign a zero to a certain set of indices I have to use
> apostrophes

Because you use wrong `printf` format specifier. If you want yo print integer use `%d` not `%c`.

`printf("%d ", accumulator[i][j]);`